# Simplifying Sums of Product Expression obtained from 8-3 Priority Encoder (Computer Science)

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have an example for simplifying expressions in sums of product form, but I can't figure out which algebraic theorem was used to get rid of some of the variables:

Step 1. (A'B'C'D'E'F'G) + (A'B'C'D'E) + (A'B'C) + (A)

which simplifies to:

Step 2. (B'D'F'G + B'D'E + B'C + A)

Which simplifies to:

Step 3. [B'(D'F'G + D'E + C) + A]

At step 2, I am confused at how the A', C', and E' terms are gone. Can anyone explain which algebraic properties were used, or show me how the simplification was done?

Thanks!

[This example was obtained from here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_4.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity

```
x + x'y = x + y
```

is repeated used above for simplification

For example.,

```
A'B'C'D'E + A'B'C'D'E'F'G = A'B'C'D'[E + E'(F'G)] = A'B'C'D'[E + F'G] 
A'B'C + A'B'C'D'E = A'B'[C + C'D'E] = A'B'[C + C'(D'E)] = A'B'[C + D'E]
```

Comment: if you understood, just mark it correct as it will be useful for others or comment more for further explanation

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand it!